# Duplicate Mars colonization questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Two questions which seem to be essentially the same question of colonizing Mars versus a space station:

- [Feasibility: self-sustaining colony on Mars vs. Space Station](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4748/26446) (June 2014, 3 answers)
- [Why Mars instead of a space station?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45494/26446) (July 2020, 12 answers)

Three questions which seem to be essentially the same question of colonizing Mars versus the Moon:

- [Which are the reasons for wanting to have a colony in Mars first than in the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34349/26446) (Feb 2019, 2 answers)
- [What are the advantages of building a human colony on Mars vs the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44445/26446) (May 2020, 4 answers)
- [What are the advantages of building a human colony on the Moon vs Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44514/26446) (June 2020, 2 answers)

Any opinions on closing or merging these questions?

Comment: IMO Feb 2019 and May 2020 are different because the former focuses on why you would want to do Mars *first*, while the latter focuses on what is *better* about Mars overall. June 2020 is a distinct follow-up question focusing on what is better about the Moon.

Comment: The June 2014 and July 2020 questions do seem to be essentially the same thing though. Might be worth a closer look to see what a merge would look like.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it will be a problem that occurs with increasing frequency as we hear more about SpaceX, Starship and the Mars program. More people will come up with this question of their own accord and will post without checking. So something should be done.

However the answers are likely to change over the years as we learn more so I would not be keen to see questions merged that were separated by too many years, but would be if they had been asked within a year or two.